# Marquee text is no working properly in samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, marquee

I have done a marquee text. I did this by the following code snippet

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scrolltext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/scrolltext"
        android:textColor="#F4CE6B" />
```

Problem is that it is not working properly in some  phones like samsung Galaxy s3. The complete text is not displayed. Instead of that only few dotes are there.

Comment: put code in java textView.setSelected(true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue.

I made a mistake in my coding by calling an additional scrolling movement method.

```
scroll_text.setText(scroll); 
scroll_text.setSelected(true);
scroll_text.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Now it seems to be ok by removing that line of code.

```
scroll_text. set Selected(true);
scroll_text.setText(scroll);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/scrolltext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Simple application that shows how to use marquee, with a long text"
        android:textColor="#F4CE6B" />
```

This worked for me.also give this in your activity's onCreate()

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scrolltext);
textView.setSelected(true);

Comment: you used android:layout_width="match_parent" change it to "wrap_content" it will work